# How to get keyboard input to measure dynamically in power bi using dax?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to show measure value in the card Visual, I'm creating two measures `Measure1` and `Measure2`, as follow:

```
Measure1 = User Keyboard input
Measure2 = Measure1
```

In card Visual, we need to show `Measure2`.

It's possible or how to give dynamic user keypress input in power bi measure.

Comment: Use "WHAT IF" parameter described here:

https://www.antaresanalytics.net/post/2018/09/11/power-bi-creating-user-input-variables

Comment: but sometimes enter number not getting exactly I'm entring  30017344 getting 300173427 and start range is 300100000 and end is 300200000 increment value is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution, by following the steps

I have created a new Parameter under the Modeling tab

[image]

After creating New measure Parameter, One new table, and measure, column got created inside pane

I have used that table parameter column and measure Parameter value
**Parameter Table**

```
Column: Parameter = GENERATESERIES(0, 500, 1)
Measure: Parameter Value = SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter'[Parameter], "")
```

[image]

Will use new measure value in measure two or display tile.

[image]